# Implementing sum on Boolean with Grover algorithm

Tags: qiskit, grovers-algorithm, kraus-representation

We are trying to implement a "sum over 4 booleans = k" in the spirit of Grover search. First, we have 4 qubits, one for each boolean `q00, q01, q02, q03,;` then 4 qubits to computed intermediate sum (`q11` and `q10` to store `"q00+q01"` where `q11` is the carry, etc);  then 3 qubits to binary represent the int result `q22.q21.q20` (varying between 0 to 3); and then a final qubit to test the result = k (here we want `k=1` so `001` is the good result, then 2 X gate on `q21` and `q22` will bring `111` via the C3Not into `q40.` Finally `q60` is for Grover extraction.

First we describe the sum (Oracle), then Grover Amplification (separated with a barrier); and done 2 iterations before measurements.

The histogram result is quite strange despite we found the standard 4 solutions, 0000 and 1111 appear also.
Can someone explain this behaviour?

[image: Circuit sum over boolean = k]
[image: Histogram k=1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the mistake.
In the first figure, when we compute q2x from q1x by :
1/ purple ccnot for the carry 
2/ blue cnot for the summation
we unroll them in the wrong way (purple then blue instead blue then purple).